# Java Scanner misses first line when reading unicode file

Tags: java, unicode, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read unicode text from a tile using java Scanner. But it reads blank for the first line, next lines are reading properly. If I add english text in first line of the file it reads properly. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"), "UTF-8");
        while(sc.hasNext())
             System.out.println(sc.nextLine());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(sc!=null) sc.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the input.txt content

```
নমঃ নমঃ নামো   বাঙালাদেশ মম
চির মনোরম       চির মধুর
বৃকে নিরবধি       বহে শত নদী
চরণে জলধির      বাজে নূপুর।।
গ্রীষ্মে নাচে বামা   কালবোশেখি ঝড়ে
সহসা বরষাতে    কাঁদিয়া ভেঙ্গে পড়ে
শরতে হেসে চলে   শেফালিকা-তলে
```

and this is the output of executing above code
     ﻿
   [image]

I have investigated more and found that it reads 65279 character at the beginning of first line and that is why the first line is not showing. Why is this happening.

By the way, there is no issue of reading in I add english text in first lline of input file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your same exact code, and copied your file contents (as pasted) inside a file in my local directory, and this is what I get as program output:

```
নমঃ নমঃ নামো   বাঙালাদেশ মম
চির মনোরম       চির মধুর
বৃকে নিরবধি       বহে শত নদী
চরণে জলধির      বাজে নূপুর।।
গ্রীষ্মে নাচে বামা   কালবোশেখি ঝড়ে
সহসা বরষাতে    কাঁদিয়া ভেঙ্গে পড়ে
শরতে হেসে চলে   শেফালিকা-তলে
```

The first line is showing correctly, unlike the example you show in your post.  I also tried regular English characters, and it shows the same behavior.

This is how the file looks:

```
/tmp> cat input1.txt 
নমঃ নমঃ নামো   বাঙালাদেশ মম
চির মনোরম       চির মধুর
বৃকে নিরবধি       বহে শত নদী
চরণে জলধির      বাজে নূপুর।।
গ্রীষ্মে নাচে বামা   কালবোশেখি ঝড়ে
সহসা বরষাতে    কাঁদিয়া ভেঙ্গে পড়ে
শরতে হেসে চলে   শেফালিকা-তলে

/tmp> wc -c input1.txt
     518 input1.txt
```

As you can see, the file shows exactly the same as the output, and the total characters, as counted by `wc -c` is only 518, not the 65K+ you mention in your post. Can you retry using the text you actually pasted in your question?

Comment: OK, I ran on windows machine. and 65279 is not total character count. Its the first character reading from first line. Due to this character at start of first line the whole first-line is not displaying.